# How can I put scrollbar into accordion menu in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

i'building an accordion menu:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  /* Cambiare l'effetto da utilizzare */
  $.easing.def = "easeOutBounce";

  /* Associare una funzione all'evento click sul link */
  $('li.title a').click(function(e){

    /* Finding the drop down list that corresponds to the current section: */
    var subMenu = $(this).parent().next();

    /* Trovare il sotto menu che corrisponde alla voce cliccata */
    $('.sub-menu').not(subMenu).slideUp('slow');
    subMenu.stop(false,true).slideToggle('slow');

    /* Prevenire l'evento predefinito (che sarebbe di seguire il collegamento) */
    e.preventDefault();
  })

});
```

does anybody know how can I put a scroll bar into a accordion menu? 
Thanx!

Comment: @Ladineko because the answer is not only for OP but for people who fin the answer later. Also because YOU would learn in the process and 3rd because you could earn points from up-votes anyway.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira please don't accept answers randomly to better your score, please take your time and be sure it is the correct answer.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira great! I'm working on your answer btw, give me 5 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L29r8/1/).

The code:

You just need a normal accordion and set the overflow property and height in this example:

```
p{
    height:80px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

​